# set item level permission using RESTAPI in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I am using a workflow to set item level permission. But it is not working. I already used some suggestion, like `break role inheritance`, `add role`. But it is not working.

I also tried it using simple `rest API` call in a browser console.
role inheritance is breaking successfully through rest API.
But when i tried to assign a new role, it is not working.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you share the snippet of what you are trying to do in the question. It would help us help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Great article regarding this using Javascript/Rest api can be [found here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/fc34aa/break-inheritance-and-add-role-permissions-using-rest-api-in/)

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, This is possible in workflow using REST API. Below are the steps which you need to follow.

Step 1: Whatever REST you are writing that should be part of **App Step**.
[image]

[image]

Step 2:  As shown in screen shot you will have to write your commands in a workflow. There are some variables which you need to assign.

Step 3: Very first, you need to build dictionary where as variable name is **ContextHeaders** in aboveshown screenshot.

[image]
[image]

Step 4: Next need to set API url in very next line. That API url should be something like **https://YourSite/_api/contextinfo** and HTTP method should be HTTP Post.

Step 5: Next you need to set **Get** and that should be like **d/GetContextWebInformation/FormDigestValue**

Step 6: Again you need to build your dictionary for request headers to make REST call to break inheritance.

[image]
[image]

Step 7: Next you need to set variable to whom you want to give permissions after breaking the inheritance.
 In example shown above, we are assign some group ids to variable **userIds**.

Step 8: Write REST to break the inheritance. Your REST should look like
**https://YourSite/_api/web/lists/getByTitle(%27YourListTitle%27)/items(%27[%Current Item:ID%]%27)/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=false, clearSubscopes=true)**. HTTP Request Type will be HTTP POST.

As we are breaking item level inheritance that's  why we are going with Current Item ID.

Step 9: You need to set variable **roleDefinition**. This role definition is for, what permission level you want to assign to particular user.group ID.

Step 10: For assigning unique permission to User/Group id, again you will have to make a REST call. your REST should look like **https://YourSite/_api/web/lists/getByTitle(%27YoutListTitle%27)/items(%27[%Current Item:ID%]%27)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=[%Variable: Id%],roledefid=[%Variable: roleDefination%])**

This is how you can break inheritance and assign unique permissions.

I hope this will help you. Still, if you have any thing, please write back.