# change the permissions of spgroup from contributenodelete to read and retain other groups permissions as its

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, item-level-permissions, item-added

I have 2 groups namely NPD ADMIN and NPD SPUSERS

AT THE DOC.LIb level, I have permisionss set as

1. `NPD ADMIN` : `CONTRIBUTE`
2. `NPD SPUSERS` : `CONTRIBUTENODELETE`

I want to remove the existing permissions for `NPD SPUSERS` group from `contributenodelete` to `read` when an item is added in this doc.lib.
so i added an eventreceiver and i added the itemadded() methods i treid to add the code to implement this business usecase.

but its not happening.
can anyone help, how to achieve this?

```
        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                SPSite CurrentSite = new SPSite(properties.SiteId);
                SPWeb CurrentWeb = 
             CurrentSite.OpenWeb(properties.RelativeWebUrl);
                CurrentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPList CurrentList = CurrentWeb.Lists[properties.ListId];
                SPListItem CurrentListItem;
                CurrentListItem = 
        CurrentWeb.Lists[properties.ListId].GetItemById(properties.
      ListItem.ID);
           SPDocumentLibrary objProjdocLib = CurrentList as 
          SPDocumentLibrary;

                SPGroup npdadminGroup = CurrentWeb.SiteGroups["NPD Admin"];
                SPGroup npdspusersGroup = CurrentWeb.SiteGroups["NPD 
          SPUsers"];

                SPFieldUserValue userValue = new 
            SPFieldUserValue(CurrentWeb, 
          CurrentListItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.Author].
         ToString());
                SPUser objspauthor = userValue.User;
                SPListItemCollection configILPItemCollection = null;

                     if ((!CurrentListItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments))
                        {
                            CurrentListItem.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
                            CurrentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        }

                //SPGroup group = root.SiteGroups[groupName];

                             SPRoleDefinition contributeRoleDef = 
          CurrentWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Contributor);
                SPRoleDefinition contributeRoleDef1 = 
        CurrentWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Contributor);

                //SPRoleDefinition contributeRoleDef = 
        CurrentWeb.RoleDefinitions["ContributeNoDelete"];
                //SPRoleDefinition readerRoleDef = CurrentWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);

                SPRoleDefinition readerRoleDef = 
            CurrentWeb.RoleDefinitions["ContributeNoDelete"];
                  SPRoleAssignment groupRoleAssignments = 
           CurrentWeb.RoleAssignments.GetAssignment
        ByPrincipal(npdadminGroup);
                //groupRoleAssignments.RoleDefinitionBindings.Remove(contributeRoleDef1);
                SPRoleAssignment groupRoleAssignments1 = CurrentWeb.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(npdspusersGroup);
                groupRoleAssignments1.RoleDefinitionBindings.Remove(contributeRoleDef);
                //groupRoleAssignments.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(readerRoleDef);
                //groupRoleAssignments.Update(); 

               CurrentListItem.RoleAssignments.Add(groupRoleAssignments);
               CurrentListItem.RoleAssignments.Add(groupRoleAssignments1);

                CurrentListItem.Update();
```

Comment: Same thing is possible with the help of workflow and the same question is replied here. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/221922/set-item-level-permission-using-restapi-in-sharepoint/221927#221927

Comment: Why this question was down voted? :-(

Comment: I don't know about that