# Workflow - Add Target Audience in create item in list Action

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have created a workflow to insert an item in a list automatically, when an item is created on the main List and it works fine.
Now, i enabled Target Audience on the target list, and wish to include instructions in workflow to publish a value to that Column/field Target Audience automatically. The value is a sharepoint group in a person column. I have tried numerous ways with no sucess.
Can you tell me how to do this if possible?
Thanks

Comment: If I understood you correctly, when item is created in one list, new item is created in another list and in second list on created item you want unique permissions?

Comment: Hi, yes that is the ideal solution, to have unique permissions assigned to Items of a List (the second list in this case). As a workaround i assigned Target Audience filtering on Web Parts and have succeeded in creating a view with distinct web parts (List Views) with Target Audience.

Comment: if you solved it than great! I had similar task, and what I did was get that ShP group, loop in it as many times as there are users in it. For each user I had to give permission with rest api call command. here is good explanation of it https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/221922/set-item-level-permission-using-restapi-in-sharepoint